# Mutate across with 2 conditions, one on variable name and the second on variable type

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-conditions

Let say I have the following table:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a1 = 1:5,
  b1 = as.character(1:5),
  c  = 1:5 
)

> df
  a1 b1 c
1  1  1 1
2  2  2 2
3  3  3 3
4  4  4 4
5  5  5 5
```

I would like to modify columns which name ends with "1" and which are numerical (meaning, only `a1` and not `c`). I'm trying to ask this double condition in a `mutate(across(where...` without success. The condition regarding the columns' name is excluded.

The following script modifies both `a1` and `c`.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      where(~ ends_with('1') && is.numeric(.)),
       ~ .x * 2
    ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `where()` for name-testing functions like `ends_with()`. You can use

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      ends_with('1') & where(is.numeric),
      ~ .x * 2
  ))
#   a1 b1 c
# 1  1  1 1
# 2  2  2 2
# 3  3  3 3
# 4  4  4 4
# 5  5  5 5
```

Also be careful with `&&`, it is only used for  length-1 inputs, you need to use `&` for vectorization.